# pyopencl.RuntimeError: clWaitForEvents failed: exec status error for events in wait list

Tags: pyopencl

Every so often I am not able to continue to run PyOpenCL on my machine.  This occasionally happens if I kill a process that is using it.  Across ALL pyopencl scripts/kernels, including examples I find online I get the following error:

```
pyopencl.RuntimeError: clWaitForEvents failed: exec status error for events in wait list
```

which follows any call of the form

```
kernel.(queue,gs,ls,...).wait()
```

OR
    a = kernel.(queue,gs,ls,...)
    a.wait()

Rebooting my machine resolves the issue, but this is a painful work around.  Has anyone run into anything similar and know how to reset things?

Thank you

Comment: I have similar problems. So far I use the same work around.